# Bake indirect lightmap

Tags: texture-baking

After extensive research I still could not find a way to do this in Blender.
Does Blender support baking indirect lightmaps?
I'm not talking about lightmaps baked with a sky light. I'm talking about lightmaps which contain only bounce lighting (from direct lighting) and no direct lighting.
We need a separate direct and indirect lightmap for our game, so we can mix baked lighting correctly with dynamic lighting.

[image: What we get]
What we get (as a lightmap)

[image: What we need]
What we need (as a lightmap)

Comment: I am not sure but I don't think this is currently possible with cycles at least. Due to the nature of the unbiased render it may be impossible to separate or determine what is "direct" and "indirect" light. It might be possible with Blender internal though, haven't used it in a while.

Comment: Technically it's not a problem for a biased/unbiased renderer to support this. All it has to do is _not_ store the result of the first hit.

Comment: Yes, it might be possible I was just not sure if it is currently implemented in Cycles or not. Apparently according to the answer bellow it *is* possible and I was wrong.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[image: Cycles Baking: Turn off the direct contribution.]

If you are baking with Cycles you just have to turn off the direct contribution when baking.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what we were looking for. Our artist already tried that ages ago, but it turns out he made a mistake somewhere else.